# How can i stop a for-loop iterating when the input is not valid? (not allowed to use a while loop) - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

```
for i in range (0, 3): 
    
    print() # When iterates creates a space from last section
    
    raw_mark = int(input("What was student: " + str(student_id[i]) + "'s raw mark (0 - 100)?: "))
    
    days_late = int(input("How many days late was that student (0 - 5)?: "))
    
    penalty = (days_late * 5)
    
    final_mark = (raw_mark - penalty)

    # Selection for validation 
    
    if 0 <= raw_mark <= 100 and 0 <= days_late <= 5 and final_mark >= 40:
        
        print("Student ID:", str(student_id[i]))
        
        print() # Spacing for user readability
        
        print("Raw mark was:", str(raw_mark),"but due to the assignment being handed in",
              str(days_late),"days late, there is a penalty of:", str(penalty),"marks.")
        
        print()
        
        print("This means that the result is now:", final_mark,"(this was not a capped mark)")

         
        
    elif 0 <= raw_mark <= 100 and 0 <= days_late <= 5 and final_mark < 40: # Final mark was below 40 so mark must be capped
        
        print("Student ID:", str(student_id[i]))
        
        print()
        
        print("Raw mark was:", str(raw_mark),"but due to the assignment being handed in",
              str(days_late),"days late, there is a penalty of:", str(penalty),"marks.")
        
        print()
        
        print("Therefore, as your final mark has dipped below 40, we have capped your grade at 40 marks.")

        
    else:
        print("Error, please try again with applicable values")
```

At the else i would like the loop to loop back through but not having iterated i to the next value, so that it can be infinite until all 3 valid inputs are entered... cannot use a while loop nor can i put the if - elif- else outside the loop. Nor can i use a function :(

Comment: The only reasonable thing to have an infinite loop would be to use a `while` loop. A bad thing to do would be to put your code in a function that calls itself recursively until the entry is valid, but that can create a whole lot of problems and can't be infinite anyway, as there is a limit to the recursion depth. So, if it's homework, it's a bad constraint for such a problem.

Comment: Yes, i agree that it is a bad constraint, i have asked if the program can end and a user would have to restart it but he said it must only end when all 3 correct inputs are put in even if there are incorrect inputs.

Comment: I had written it out and it worked as a while loop but lecturer said must be a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your for loop behave like a while loop and have it run forever and implement your i as a counter. Then the loop can be terminated only if it ever hits 3 (or 2 so that you indices dont change), while otherwise it is set back to 0:

```
cnt_i = -1
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    cnt_i += 1
    if ...

    else:
        cnt_i = 0
    if cnt_i == 2:
        break
```

But seriously, whatever the reason for not using a while loop, you should use it anyhow..

Comment: Thank you, i'll have to do it this way. I have just emailed my lecturer again about the problem as i believe you would only use a while loop for this problem and not a for loop as the range could be infinite if the inputs are always entered incorrectly. Thank you

Comment: Also, in that case, the lesson learned in your lecture is probably, "this is why sometime you should use while loops"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can keep track of the number of valid inputs, and only stop your loop (the `while`) once you hit your target number.

```py
valid_inputs = 0

while valid_inputs <= 3:
   ...

   if ...:
      ...
   elif ...:
      ...
   else:
      # Immediately reset to the top of the while loop
      # Does not increment valid_inputs
      continue

   valid_inputs += 1
```

Comment: From the question: "cannot use a while loop"

Comment: My mistake, I read `cannot use a while loop` as `I don't know how I would use a while loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the input statement inside while loop containing try block.

```py
for j in range(3): # or any other range
    try:
        raw_mark = int(input("What was student: " + str(student_id[i]) + "'s raw mark (0 - 100)?: "))

        days_late = int(input("How many days late was that student (0 - 5)?: "))
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: From the question: "cannot use a while loop"

Comment: Just use any for loop command instead like "for i in range(3): " inplace of "while True:"

Comment: I have remove the while loop go through the answer.

Comment: From the question too: "so that it can be infinite until all 3 valid inputs are entered"

Comment: could the except section lead to where the selection statement begins?

Comment: No if the input is correct the for loop will terminate thereonly. The `break` statement will do so.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are saying HBridges but after the except section is executed the for loop will run again

Comment: As it would pass does that mean it would not iterate the counter i if some inputs are incorrect?

Comment: My code need to use a different counter variable then i. The counter variable of your code will not be affected but my counter variable will be. Let me change my counter variable to j.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot use a while loop...

```py
def get_valid_input():
   user_input = input(...)
   valid = True
   if (...):  # Do your validation here
      valid = False

   if valid:
      return user_input
   else:
      return get_valid_input()

for i in range (0, 3): 
   input = get_valid_input()
   # Do what you need to do, basically your program from the question
   ...
   ...
```

There are some additional gotchas here, as in you need to worry about the possibility of hitting the maximum recursion limit if you keep getting bad input values, but `get_valid_input` should ideally only return when you are sure you have something that is valid.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use a function as we aren't supposed to use things we have learnt already in the course for this problem, we have learnt while loops but he wants us to use a for loop for the problem, i have tried protesting that